# Laravel 5: cannot retrieve user input from view

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have a text area input field on my posts page that I'm trying to use to submit users comments via ajax. But I keep getting the SQL error comment field cannot be empty. I am positive that I'm filling the field with data.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'comment' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `comments` (`user_id`, `comment`, `parent_id`, `parents`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, , , 0, 2015-10-16 19:16:26, 2015-10-16 19:16:26))

Doing `dd(Input::get('commenter_comment))` gives `null`

I also get this error in the console

> POST http://localhost/reddit/public/posts/post_this_comment 500 (Internal Server Error)

These are my routes

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::post('posts/post_this_comment', 'PostsController@post_this_comment');
```

`post_this_comment()` method in `PostsController`

```
public function post_this_comment(Request $request){

    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->user_id = Auth::id();
    $comment->comment = Input::get('commenter_comment');
    $comment->parent_id = Input::get('commenter_parent');
    if($comment->parent_id > 0){
        $my_parent = Comment::find($comment->parent_id);
        $comment->parents = $my_parent->parents.'.'.$comment->parent_id;
    }else{
        $comment->parents = '0';
    }
    $comment->save();
    $per_page = Input::get('per_page');
    $comment_list = view('eastgate.comment.comment_list')
        ->with('comments', $this->comment_list($per_page, $request))
        ->with('total_comments', $this->total_comments())
        ->with('per_page', $per_page)
        ->render();
    $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'msg' => 'Comment Saved!',
        'comment_list' => $comment_list
    );
    return Response::json($response);
}
```

The view

```
    <div class="comment-fields">
        <div class="row commenter-comment">
             <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <textarea id="commenter_comment" name="commenter_comment" class="form-control comment-field" title="User's comment" placeholder="Comment Text"></textarea>

              </div>
         </div>

         <div class="row commenter-name-email">
              <input type="hidden" id="commenter_parent" name="commenter_parent" class="commenter-parent" value="0">
         </div>

         <div class="row commenter-captcha">
              <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info post-this-comment">Post</a>
              </div>
         </div>

      </div>

$(document).on('click', 'a.post-this-comment', function(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    var arrayelem = commenter_fields();
    var elem;
    for(var i=0, size = arrayelem.length; i<size; i++){
        elem = arrayelem[i];
        formData.append(elem, $('#'+elem).val());
    }
    formData.append('per_page', $('.comments_per_page').val());

    var request = $.ajax({ // push question data to server
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'post_this_comment', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json',
        processData : false,
        contentType : false
    });     
    request.done(comment_done_handler); 
    request.fail(comment_fail_handler); // fail promise callback
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$comment->comment = $request->input('commenter_comment');
$comment->parent_id = $request->input('commenter_parent');
```

Finally, the issue was with the ajax request.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.post-this-comment', function(){ 
var formData = 'commenter_comment='+$('textarea[name=commenter_comment]').val(); 
//formData.append('commenter_comment', $('textarea[name=commenter_comment]').val()); 
console.log(formData); 


var request = $.ajax({ // push question data to server 
type : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form) 
url : 'post_this_comment', // the url where we want to POST 
data : formData // our data object 
}); 
request.done(comment_done_handler); 
request.fail(comment_fail_handler); // fail promise callback 
});
```

Changing to this format worked.

Comment: Didn't work. I get `Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$commenter_comment`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've edited my answer. Try this. If this doesn't work. Inside your post_this_comment just write dd($request); . Through this you'll be able to see if all your receiving all parameters on the server side or not.

Comment: Now I'm getting `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::input()`

Comment: Make sure you have type hinted 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Just write this line at the top. and remove the 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
line.

Comment: I stopped getting errors on submit but `dd($comment->comment);` still gives null

Comment: dd($request->input('commenter_comment'));
What does this give?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92542/discussion-between-itsbharat-and-halnex).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel 5.x, don't use `Input::get()` as version 5 and above suggests using `$request->input('something')`

You have to use the following:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Then you can use:

```
if($request->has('commenter_comment'))
{
    $comment->comment = $request->input('commenter_comment');
}
```

The if condition above checks if the input was actually sent and has a value. This is useful before you try to use it.

Comment: I've already tried that, still gives null on `dd($request->input('commenter_comment'))`

Comment: if that gives you null, then the request is sending that value as null. can you check the request again or post the request data here ?